# How show legend(s) only for toggled layers on map?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I create map using Mapox with 7 layers thanks to [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/toggle-layers/). This layers I can switch on and switch off on the map thanks to buttons for each layers.

At the same time I don't have any spetial knowledge in Javascript. It's restrict me to create legends (div element) for each layers. The particular legend(s) must show on the fly when particular layer(s) switched on.

I found function [L.mapbox.legendControl](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v3.1.1/l-mapbox-legendcontrol/). But how it applies for my purpose?

Where and which code have to use for make legend like pictured [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSa7I.jpg)